# Android loads values from default strings file (strings.xml) after changing locale for 2nd time

Tags: android

I am working on an android app where i change the locale (English to Arabic) on main screen with a single button. It works fine on main screen but the issue raises when i change the language more than once. 
Following steps to regenerate:

- On main (login) screen, Current Language is `English` and i change it to `Arabic`. (works fine)
- Go to signup or forgot password page and Language is changed now. (`Arabic`)
- Get back to main screen and change the locale back to `English` from `Arabic`. (Works on Login screen)
- Go to signup page and now the direction is changed but string are loaded from Arabic. (Current language is `English`)

Here is my code for changing locale.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.text.TextUtilsCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.Locale;

public class LocaleSettings {

public static final String LANGUAGE_ENGLISH = "en";
public static final String LANGUAGE_ARABIC = "ar";
public static final String CURRENT_LANGUAGE = "currentLanguage";

/**
 * Loads the current language of application
 *
 * @param context current context, pass "this" for current view context
 */
public static void loadLocal(Context context) {
    setLocal(context, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(CURRENT_LANGUAGE, ""));
}

/**
 * This fucntion sets the application language
 *
 * @param context - current context. pass "this" for current view context
 * @param lang    Language String, i.e. "en" or "ar"
 */
public static void setLocal(Context context, String lang) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.setLocale(locale);
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString(CURRENT_LANGUAGE, lang);
    editor.apply();
    editor.commit();
}

/**
 * Use to change application language using current context
 *
 * @param context pass "this" for current view context
 */
public static void switchLanguage(Context context) {
    if (getCurrentLanguage(context).equals(LANGUAGE_ENGLISH))
        setLocal(context, LANGUAGE_ARABIC);
    else
        setLocal(context, LANGUAGE_ENGLISH);
}

/**
 * Get application current active language
 *
 * @param context pass "this" for current view context
 * @return String - language string i.e. en or ar
 */
public static String getCurrentLanguage(Context context) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(CURRENT_LANGUAGE, "");
}

public static boolean isRTL(String locale) {
    return TextUtilsCompat.getLayoutDirectionFromLocale(new Locale(locale)) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL ? true : false;
}

public static void enforceDirectionIfRTL(Context context){
    if(isRTL(getCurrentLanguage(context))){
        ((Activity) context).getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    }

}
```

}

Here is code for login activity

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button loginButton = null;
    private EditText account_no = null;
    private EditText password = null;
    final UserApi userApi = JoezdanServiceGenerator.createService(UserApi.class);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LocaleSettings.loadLocal(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        configureLanaguageButton();

    }

    private void configureLanaguageButton() {

        final ImageButton selectLocale = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectLanguage);
        selectLocale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LocaleSettings.switchLanguage(LoginActivity.this);
                recreate();
            }
        });

    }

... eliminating irrelevant code
}
```

This is my first android app so pardon me if there are mistakes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which device are you using for testing? What is the SDK level?

Comment: @nhp my minimum sdk is 17 and max is 28. The worst thing is that it works fine on my phone (huawei y7 prime) but not works on emulator and TESTER's phone.

Comment: try my code below it should work

Comment: Kindly check my answer @Shahzeb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to make sure that after the user change locals you close all the activities and restart app,  something like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AcSettingsView.this, MainActivityView.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finishAffinity();
```

Another thing to watch for is to make sure you set your locals everytime app starts 
in your first screen like this

```
helper = new PreferenceHelper(this);
        String lang = helper.getData(Constants.LANGUAGE_CODE);
            if (eng) {
                Utility.setLocale(getBaseContext(), Constants.ENGLISH_CODE);
            } else {
                Utility.setLocale(getBaseContext(), Constants.ARABIC_CODE);
            }
```

Comment: in your case you would check in SharedPreferences what lang you are using and call LocaleSettings .setLocal and give the the key

Comment: Thank you, this is working now but it since it restarts the activity, the change "activity restart" is noticeable. is there any way user does not experience the restart of the activity?

Comment: you cant, if you go to any big app like messanger or whatsapp and change lang you will notice the app is restarting

Answer (score 1):

From the Android documentation:

> Android by default uses the locale of the device to select the appropriate language dependent resources. And most of the time this behaviour is enough for **common** applications.

**Changing language internally is an exception.**

First, please read [this documentation](https://proandroiddev.com/change-language-programmatically-at-runtime-on-android-5e6bc15c758) and acknowledge the pitfalls of the design.

To summarize, here are 2 things that I want to mention:

1. `updateConfiguration` is deprecated, so we need another version to support backward compatible.
2. We need to override `attachBaseContext` to every activity to reflect changes.

Here is the implementation:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    configuration.setLocale(locale);
    configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = locale;
    configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    return context;
}
```

In order to support backward compatible, check version before changing language:

```
public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
    // You can save SharedPreference here

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return updateResources(context, language);
    }

    return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
}
```

In your `LoginActivity`, after changing the locale, you don't have to recreate the activity, you can get the resource then change every `TextView` manually.

```
Context context = LocaleUtils.setLocale(this, lang);
Resources resources = context.getResources();
yourFirstTextView.setText(resources.getString(R.string.your_first_text_res)
// ... yourSecondTextView....
```

In every activity, to reflect changes, add this function:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleUtils.onAttach(newBase));
}
```

Btw, there is a bug, you can't change title language of `Toolbar`. In your `onCreate()`, call this function manually, `setTitle("your Title")`

I know these kind issues are ugly, and the solutions are a little bit hacky. But let give it a try. Let me know if that helps you out. :)

Full source code can be found here: https://github.com/gunhansancar/ChangeLanguageExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/gunhansancar/changelanguageexample/helper/LocaleHelper.java

with greate article: https://gunhansancar.com/change-language-programmatically-in-android/